# Navbar hides when page hits top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following problem: The navbar is supposed to hide when scrolling down and appear when scrolling up. Works perfectly in Firefox, but in Chrome and Safari (and other browsers?) the navbar hides also when I scroll back up and hit the very top of the page, so the little "bounce" created when hitting the top and it "snaps" back into original position creats a down sroll that tells the navbar to hide again. It is the opposite thing when reaching the end, due to the "bounce" at the botton that creates the upscroll "snap" and the navbar appears. I want both of these events to not happen (the little bounces should get ignored if that is possible). I know what causes the problem but I do not know how to engage and manipulate the responsible elements. As you might have noticed I am a beginner and just entering the world of JavaScript, so any explanations beside a solution are appreaciated. I am using normalize.css as well if that is necessary information. I hope I have provided every relevant code snippet. Thanks in advance, this place is dope!

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("fader").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("fader").style.top = "-100%";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
.nav-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<header class="nav-wrapper bg-dark" id="fader">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <img class="pic" src="assets/pic.svg" alt="Pic" />
    <img class="logo" src="assets/logo.svg" alt="Logo" />
    <div class="menu-toggle" id="mobile-menu">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav no-search">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#one">One</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#five">Five</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Show the `#fader` styles on your css. There should be the offending issue.

Comment: I have not asserted any styles to the #fader. I only engage with it in JavaScript. How would you style it and what do I need to tell my code to act correctly?

Comment: Sorry, but I have not installed Chrome neither Safari on my phone to run your code. But maybe you can use css to avoid this behavior as it works perfectly in Firefox. Try `animate translate`

Comment: I will try, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I added Math.abs(prevScrollPos) and it cleared it up for the top.

Based on some research on the scroll position it returns a number that is an inverted y axis, the numbers get bigger the farther “down” the page you go. The zero is at the very top of your page. When that bounce occurs at the top you enter a negative Y axis. Your previous position is no longer greater than your current position and the Navbar disappears. If you make the y axis absolute values it resolves the issue.